# how to clone table by SQL alchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a table with no model in SQLAlchemy, for example, `names` in my database and I want to clone it with a new name `names_clone`.
How can this be achieved in SQLAlchemy without using SQLAlchemy Models?

```
db_url = "some DB URL engine"
engine = create_engine(db_url)
meta = MetaData(bind=engine)
inspector = inspect(engine)
table = Table("names", meta, autoload=True)
# I want do some thing like blow
new_table = table.copy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I code like this and

```
columns = []
for column in table.columns:
    columns.append(Column(column.name, column.type, primary_key=column.primary_key,
                              autoincrement=column.autoincrement))
new_table = Table(
    new_name, meta
    , *columns
)
result = meta.create_all(engine, tables=[new_table])

query = new_table \
    .insert() \
    .from_select(names=[column.name for column in new_table.columns],
                 # array of column names that your query returns
                 select=select([table]))

result = connection.execute(query)
```